# Writing and reading struct array in C

Tags: c, struct, fwrite, fread

I am trying to write a structure to a file and then read it. The structure contains two elements:

```
struct person {
    int id;
    char name[10];
};
```

And here is my main() function that works correctly:

```
int main ()
{
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen ("person.dat", "w+");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError with opening the file\n");
        exit (1);
    }

    struct person input[2];
    struct person output[2];

    input[0].id=1;
    strcpy(input[0].name, "AAA");
    input[0].name[3]='\0';
    input[1].id=2;
    strcpy(input[1].name, "BBB");
    input[1].name[3]='\0';

    // write struct to file
    if( (fwrite(input, sizeof(struct person), 2, fp))!=2)
        printf("Error with writing to file!\n");
    //move to the beginning of the file
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    //read struct from file
    if( (fread(output, sizeof(struct person), 2, fp))!=2)
        printf("Error with reading from file!\n");
    printf ("id = %d name = %s \n", output[0].id, output[0].name);
    printf ("id = %d name = %s \n", output[1].id, output[1].name);
    // close file
    fclose (fp);

    return 0;
}
```

However, I would like to use a loop to initialize the elements. Therefore I used a for loop to do it instead of initializing them one by one:

```
for(i=0; i<2; i++)
{
    input[i].id=i;
    strcpy(input[i].name, "AAA");
    input[i].name[3]='\0';
}
```

Unfortunately, if I use for loop I got a message: Error with reading from file!
The values for first element of the array are correct(id = 0 and name = AAA) but second element has some random values. I don't see a reason why using for loop instead of initializing each element separately would have an impact on the reading from file. Could it be that something with my fread or fwrite functions is incorrect?

Comment: BTW: `input[0].name[3]='\0';` etc. is not necessary, `strcpy` already does the job.

Comment: Hint: check the actual return value of `fread` (by inserting an appropriate  `printf` for example). This may give you additional information about what could have gone wrong

Comment: strcpy() appends a '\0' to the end of destination string so input[0].name[3]='\0'; is superfluous.

Comment: It works fine when I replace it with a loop. Did you change anything else?

Comment: Thank you for the idea. The fread returns value 1. So it looks like it reads only the first element of the struct array.

Comment: No I didn't change anything else. It's exactly the same code I was running on my computer. I use CodeBlocks IDE and gcc compiler on Windows 7. I can test it on Linux next week. Could there be any difference?

Comment: You mention Windows. Maybe you need to add the 'b' (for binary) to fopen()?

Comment: If you use a loop, you must use a seek or flush statement between the read and the next write operations, as described in [fopen](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=vs-2017) further down under the discussion about file opening modes, which also mentions binary/text opening modes. In Windows you should be specific about binary or text modes, to prevent the conversion of newline characters (which is done even where there is no textual context to the data – `fread` and `fwrite` don't care: it's just data). If it "worked" for Artyer that was UB.

Comment: Thank you Bjorn you were correct! I used wb+ instead of w+ and now it works as it should! I was reading a lot about structures, fwrite and fread but I would never think that I should have opened it in binary mode. Thank you Weather about the information about seek or flush statements, I didn't know about it.

Comment: Remember to use like @BjornA. if you want to flag another user (only one per comment is allowed).